# How can you load a CSV into PyFlink as a Streaming Table Source?

Tags: python, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I am trying to setup a simple playground environment to use the Flink Python Table API. The Jobs I am ultimately trying to write will feed off of a Kafka or Kenesis queue, but that makes playing around with ideas (and tests) very difficult.

I can happily load from a CSV and process it in Batch mode. But I cannot get it to work in Streaming Mode. How would I do something similar but in a StreamingExecutionEnvironment (primarily so I can play around with windows).

I understand that I need to get the system to use EventTime (because ProcTime would all come in at once), but I cannot find anyway to set this up. In principle I should be able to set one of the columns of the CSV to be the event time, but it is not clear form the docs how to do this (or if it is possible).

To get the Batch execution tests running I used the below code, which reads from an `input.csv` and outputs to an `output.csv`.

```py
from pyflink.dataset import ExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import (
    TableConfig,
    DataTypes,
    BatchTableEnvironment,
    StreamTableEnvironment,
)
from pyflink.table.descriptors import Schema, Csv, OldCsv, FileSystem
from pathlib import Path

exec_env = ExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
exec_env.set_parallelism(1)
t_config = TableConfig()
t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(exec_env, t_config)
root = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
out_path = root / "output.csv"

try:
    out_path.unlink()
except:
    pass

from pyflink.table.window import Tumble

(
    t_env.connect(FileSystem().path(str(root / "input.csv")))
    .with_format(Csv())
    .with_schema(
        Schema().field("time", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3)).field("word", DataTypes.STRING())
    )
    .create_temporary_table("mySource")
)

(
    t_env.connect(FileSystem().path(str(out_path)))
    .with_format(Csv())
    .with_schema(
        Schema().field("word", DataTypes.STRING()).field("count", DataTypes.BIGINT())
    )
    .create_temporary_table("mySink")
)

(
    t_env.from_path("mySource")
    .group_by("word")
    .select("word, count(1) as count")
    .filter("count > 1")
    .insert_into("mySink")
)

t_env.execute("tutorial_job")
```

and input.csv is

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000000000,james
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000000000,james
2002-01-01 00:00:00.000000000,steve
```

So my question is how could I set it up so that it reads from the same CSV, but uses the first column as the event time and allow me to write code like:

```py
(
    t_env.from_path("mySource")
    .window(Tumble.over("10.minutes").on("time").alias("w"))
    .group_by("w, word")
    .select("w, word, count(1) as count")
    .filter("count > 1")
    .insert_into("mySink")
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I cant work this out from the docs. I am using `python 3.7` and `flink 1.11.1` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the descriptor API, you can specify a field is the event-time field through the schema:

```
.with_schema(  # declare the schema of the table
             Schema()
             .field("rowtime", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP())
             .rowtime(
                Rowtime()
                .timestamps_from_field("time")
                .watermarks_periodic_bounded(60000))
             .field("a", DataTypes.STRING())
             .field("b", DataTypes.STRING())
             .field("c", DataTypes.STRING())
         )
```

But I still recommend you to use [DDL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#defining-in-create-table-ddl-1), on the one hand it is easier to use, on the other hand there are some bugs in the existing Descriptor API, the community is discussing refactoring the Descriptor API

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using watermark strategies? As mentioned [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#introduction-to-watermark-strategies), you need to use watermark strategies to use event time. For pyflink case, personally i think it is easier to declare it in the ddl format like [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#defining-in-create-table-ddl-1).